# How can I convert a date to DatePicker value format in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker, frontend

I want to convert "22.11.2022 00:00:00" to Mon Nov 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) and set picker value.

My code:

```
view.picker.setValue(this.jsonData.dateData)
```

I tried

```
console.log(Ext.Date.format(dt, 'l, \\t\\he jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')); // Wednesday, the 10th of January 2007 03:05:01 PM
```

but it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that the [datepicker](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.picker.Date.html) expects a JavaScript Date as it's value. You could easily achieve that by creating a new JavaScript Date using `new Date(this.jsonData.dateData)`. Since you are getting a german Date/String represenation this would still not work.

If you change to the correct formatting you should get a valid Date Object that you can set to the picker.

```
const   dateString = "22.11.2022 00:00:00",
        dateObject = new Date(dateString.replace(/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)/, '$2-$1-$3'));

picker.setValue(dateObject);
```

Here is a working example: [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3m2o)

Comment: Hello, it's worked. But my dateString "01.12.2022" converted to dateObject as " Wed Jan 12 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)" but I want dateObject as "Thu Dec 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)". What should I change?

Comment: I solved it with var otoDate = new Date((data.date).replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1'));. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because this question is related to ExtJS, i would suggest the following

```
Ext.Date.parse('22.11.2022 00:00:00', 'd.m.Y H:i:s')
```

docs:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.Date.html